# Threading, inheritance

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance

My code is composed of a queue thread class (called `MyThread`), a class inheriting `MyThread` (Device) and many class inheriting `Device` (such as `A`, `B`, ...)

`Device` instantiate a FSM (state machine). So each Device (`A`, `B`,..) have the same FSM table.

Now I am trying to implement callbacks of the FSM for/in each device `A`, `B`, ...

Here is a sketch of my code:

1.Device module:

```
MAP = {
'initial' : 'none',
'events': [
    {'name': 'load', 'src': ['OFF', 'ON', 'none'], 'dst': 'LOADED'},
    ],
 'callbacks': {}
}
class Device(MyThread):
    def __init__(self, actor=None):
        MyThread.__init__(self, actor, self.__class__)
        self.MAP =MAP
        self.MAP['callbacks']['onload'] = lambda e: self.initialise()
        self.start()
    def startFSM(self):
        self.started = True
        self.fsm = Fysom(self.MAP)
        self.fsm.startup()
```

2.MyThread module:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, actor, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.actor = actor
    def run(self):
        pass
```

3.A:

```
class A(Device):    
    def __init__(self, actor=None):
        Device.__init__(self, actor)
        self.status = None
    def initialise(self):
        print "Here is A"
```

4.B:

```
class B(Device):    
    def __init__(self, actor=None):
        Device.__init__(self, actor)
        self.status = None
    def initialise(self):
        print "Here is B"
```

Current code simplified:

```
a = A()
b = B()
a.fsm.load()
b.fsm.load()
```

which will returns :

```
Here is B
Here is B
```

instead of :

```
Here is A
Here is B
```

or again:
`a.MAP['callbacks']['onload']` has same memory location as `b.MAP['callbacks']['onload']`

The point here is to focus on MAP attributes. The issue is that the function saved in `self.MAP['callbacks']['onload']` override the last one. But basically they should have one MAP per Device (A, B, ...). And each device should save is own `initialise` method into his own MAP attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
MAP = {
'initial' : 'none',
'events': [
    {'name': 'load', 'src': ['OFF', 'ON', 'none'], 'dst': 'LOADED'},
    ],
 'callbacks': {}
}
class Device(MyThread):
    def __init__(self, actor=None):
        MyThread.__init__(self, actor, self.__class__)
        self.MAP =MAP  # Problem!
```

You're making`self.MAP` a **reference** to `MAP`. So every instance of a class that inherits from `Device` ends up with a `self.MAP` property that's a reference to the exact same dict (the global `MAP` dict). What you really want is this, so that each instance gets its own dict:

```
from copy import deepcopy

MAP = {
'initial' : 'none',
'events': [
    {'name': 'load', 'src': ['OFF', 'ON', 'none'], 'dst': 'LOADED'},
    ],
 'callbacks': {}
}
class Device(MyThread):
    def __init__(self, actor=None):
        MyThread.__init__(self, actor, self.__class__)
        self.MAP = deepcopy(MAP)  # Make sure each MAP is unique.
```

Comment: I think you would need to make a deep copy of the `MAP` dictionary otherwise the copies made will share elements -- many of which are containers themselves. Another possibility might to make a `Map` class and create new instances of it for each `Device`.

Comment: @mertineau Yes, you're right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: ty for help. I tried it but nothing changed. if for example I do `a.MAP['callbacks']['onload'] = 0` it will also overrides `b.MAP['callbacks']['onload']`. I am wondering if it's not due to polymorphisme.

Comment: @Katsu I just updated the answer, I overlooked that `MAP.copy()` was only doing a shallow copy of the `MAP`. It changed the example to use `deepcopy()` which should fix the issue.

Comment: @dano&mertineau: Nice you are genious